# AttributeError when attempting to write a field on serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I try to write a recipe, where I have a dict in field ingredients. Mistake sounds like this:

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field "amount" on serializer "RecipeIngredientWriteSerializer".
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the "Ingredient" instance.
Original exception text was: 'Ingredient' object has no attribute "amount".

This is my models

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=constants.MAX_NAME_LENGTH,
        verbose_name='Название'
    )
    measurement_unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=constants.MAX_NAME_LENGTH,
        verbose_name='Единица измерения'
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Ингредиент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ингредиенты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=constants.MAX_NAME_LENGTH,
        verbose_name='Название'
    )
    text = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Описание'
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Автор',
        related_name='recipes'
    )
    cooking_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        verbose_name='Время приготовления (в минутах)',
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(
                1,
                'Допустимое значение не меньше 1'
            )
        ]
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tag,
        verbose_name='Тег',
        through='RecipeTag'
    )
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        Ingredient,
        verbose_name='Ингредиенты',
        through='RecipeIngredient'
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='recipe/images/',
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Картинка'
        )
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='Дата публикации',
        auto_now_add=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
        verbose_name = 'рецепт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'рецепты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='количество ингредиента',
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(
                1,
                'Допустимое значение не меньше 1'
            )
        ]
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'ингредиент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'ингредиенты'
```

There are serializers for writing:

```
class RecipeIngredientWriteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    amount = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    def validate_amount(self, value):
        if value <= 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'Количесто ингредиента не может быть меньше 0'
            )
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient
        fields = (
            'id',
            'amount'
        )


class RecipeWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Tag.objects.all()
    )
    image = Base64ImageField(required=True)
    ingredients = RecipeIngredientWriteSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = (
            'ingredients',
            'tags',
            'image',
            'name',
            'text',
            'cooking_time'
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ingredients = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tag in tags:
            RecipeTag.objects.create(
                tag=tag, recipe=recipe)
        for ingredient in ingredients:
            current_ingredient = get_object_or_404(
                Ingredient, id=ingredient['id']
            )
            RecipeIngredient.objects.get_or_create(
                ingredient=current_ingredient,
                amount=ingredient['amount'],
                recipe=recipe
            )
        return recipe
```

Request looks like this:

```
{
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "id": 1123,
      "amount": 10
    }
  ],
  "tags": [
    1,
    2
  ],
  "image": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAgMAAABieywaAAAACVBMVEUAAAD///9fX1/S0ecCAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAACklEQVQImWNoAAAAggCByxOyYQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
  "name": "string",
  "text": "string",
  "cooking_time": 1
}
```

What's wrong with my code? The same mistake was about reading, I solved it by adding a source to the amount field

```
amount = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='recipeingredient.amount')
```

But here it didn't worked.